# How to add newline after delimiter in Unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Below is my input

```
54.243.94.244, 54.243.113.63
```

and I want the out like below,

```
54.243.94.244
54.243.113.63
```

i.e. after comma I need to add newline.
How to achieve it in Unix? Please suggest some commands.

Comment: Do you want a newline after the comma, or do you want it to replace the comma?  Your data appears to replace the comma (and blank) with a newline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option is `tr`

```
tr ',' '\n'
```

Comment: tr "," "\n" IP_withoutTrim.txt > IP_Trim.txt
it;s not working for me getting below error!
tr: 0653-712 The combination of options and String parameters is not legal.
Usage: tr [ -[c|C] | -[c|C]ds | -[c|C]s | -ds | -s ] [-A] String1 String2
       tr { -[c|C]d | -[c|C]s | -d | -s } [-A] String1

Comment: got it.. thanks :)
cat IP_withoutTrim.txt | tr ',' '\n' > IP_Trim.txt
this worked

Comment: @GanzRicanz Good deal.  Just a tip, you can avoid the `cat` and use redirection again.  `tr ',' '\n' < IP_withoutTrim.txt > IP_Trim.txt`

Answer (score 4):

`sed` will do the trick:

```
$ echo '54.243.94.244, 54.243.113.63' | sed 's/, /\n/g'
54.243.94.244
54.243.113.63
```

The sed command `s/, /\n/g` will replace all occurrences of a comma followed by a space in the input with a newline.

Comment: hi this is not working i'm getting output like below,
54.243.94.244n54.243.113.63

Comment: @GanzRicanz: which Unix platform are you working on?  Some versions of `sed` have issues with `\n`.  Also, did you use single quotes?

Comment: Thanks Scott, my platform not supporting sed. i tried tr it's worked. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be

```
VAR1=a
VAR1="$VAR1"$'\n'b
echo "$VAR"
```

This would give output like

```
a
b
```

Comment: That works in `bash`, not in all shells.  It also doesn't address the case where you have `VAR="54.243.94.244, 54.243.113.63"` and you want to get the newline interpolated in place of the comma and blank.